# Couchbase with Spring data using spring config example

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

I am a newbie to couchbase. I am using spring in my application through which I am trying to connect to couchbase in my local. I am trying to create a couchbase template(similar to what is done in mongo template) in configurations as below:

[Spring configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBHlh.png)

[Repository using couchbase template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge9J1.png)

But when I start application, I get autowiring errors and I am unable to fetch back anything. Can some please help with above issue?
Or if someone can share sample code to extract data from couchbase using sprin-data & spring configuration? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

So you are using Spring Data Couchbase 1.4? The framework offers a dedicated namespace for the Spring xml configuration that you should use instead of attempting to call constructors:

**xml configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:couchbase="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase/spring-couchbase.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <couchbase:couchbase host="127.0.0.1,192.168.1.101" bucket="default" password=""/>

    <couchbase:template/> <!-- will use default client above, no additional tuning-->
</beans>
```

First notice the `xmlns:couchbase` and the couchbase-specific `xsi:schemaLocation` in the root.

Secondly, not providing ids will wire up beans with the default IDs (and same for references, eg. the default template will reference the default client if no "`client-ref`" attribute is specified).

Thirdly, notice the format for the "`host`" parameter is just a `String`, hostnames or ips separated by commas (in case you want to bootstrap from a cluster).

At this point the template should be available for autowiring.

**repository**

For CRUD operations, Spring Data Couchbase already comes with a `CRUDRepository` abstraction. You only need to:

- declare an interface `UsersRepository` extending `CRUDRepository<Users, String>` (string being the type of the `Users` field identifying it). Let's say it's in package `com.test.repo`.
- enable building of repositories by the framework in the xml config: [`<repositories base-package="com.test.repo" />`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring) (click for relevant section of the doc)
- autowire your repository: `@Autowired public UsersRepository repo;`

The documentation has many more details about concepts like the repositories, pre-requisites for a CRUD repository to work in couchbase (short story: you need to create a view to back it up), how to model and annotate entities, etc...

Please have a look at it, at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: notice that version `2.0` of the `Spring Data Couchbase` connector is being actively developed and should be part of the next release train of Spring Data, codename `Hopper`. It brings much more features, a good number of them being possible thanks to the `N1QL` query language introduced in `Couchbase Server 4.0`

Comment: Sorry for late response Simon. Since team had some other priority task, we got diverted to some other direction for some time. But I need to understand the issue for above problem. So I will try out the pointers you have mentioned above and will let you know if I am able to resolve the same. Thank you very much for your response!